# Opening raw binary raster in QGIS or R?

Tags: qgis, raster, r, raster-conversion

I have a raw binary raster without a file ending, and no header file. I would like to open this in either QGIS or R and then convert to geotiff, but opening it seems to be a challenge.

Here is a link to an extract or part of the original image.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17287323/test51by51_s1

The image has the following properties:

nrows: 51

ncolumns: 51

datatype: 16 bit integer

Number of bands: 1

pixel size is 231.656 x 231.656 m

For the original image, I have the coordinates for the UL pixel, but not for this extract.

Comment: Use VRT: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html  See ".vrt Descriptions for Raw Files"

Comment: Or more directly in R: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14848/problems-with-na-values-when-reading-dem-file-with-r-raster-package-in-window/15093#15093

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and R you wish to ask about in this particular question